# How to create a function that will compare the value of a variable and return the value if it does not match the pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, compare

I would like to create a `function()` whose task will be to compare the value of the `sAMAccountName` variable with the value stored in the exclusion pattern file. The values to be checked are taken with a `for loop` from the `encoded_users_from_LDAP.json` file, the pattern file is `addc_accounts_excluded.json`. In the main loop I would like to put the condition `if is_account_excluded(sAMAccountName) == False:`

part of my code:

```
with open("addc_accounts_excluded.json", 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    excluded_users = data['sAMAccountName']

with open("encoded_users_from_LDAP.json", 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    retrived_users = data['entries']


def is_account_excluded(): # this what I need to validate accounts


for user in retrived_users:
    attributes = user['attributes']
    sAMAccountName = attributes['sAMAccountName']
    if is_account_excluded(sAMAccountName) == False:
        print(sAMAccountName)
        print(attributes['cn'])
```

EDIT: I managed to solve the problem, it works but I don't know if it's written correctly

```
def is_account_excluded(suspect):
    account = False
    for account_checked in excluded_users:
        if (account_checked == suspect):
            account = True
    return account
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your problem is correct, this should work:

```
def is_account_excluded(user: str, excluded_users: str):
  return user not in excluded_users
```